# How to watch input validity from within an isolated directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to watch the validity of an input element from within a custom directive but am having issues.  I've created the following simple app

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('test', [function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      coordinate: '=ngModel',
      field: '='
    },
    require: 'ngModel',
    templateUrl:'test.tpl.html',
    link:function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){
      scope.amount = 1;
      scope.valid = true;

      scope.$watch(function(){
        return ngModel.$valid;
      }, function(value){
        scope.valid = value;
        console.log('Our ngModel is ' + value);
      });
      scope.$watch(function(){
        return scope.field.$valid;
      }, function(value){
        scope.valid = value;
        console.log('Field is valid ' + value);
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

where test.tpl.html is defined as

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" required="required" name="fruit" ng-model="fruit" />
<select class="form-control" ng-model="amount" ng-disabled="!valid">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

and it's pulled together using

```
<body>
  <form name="testForm" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : testForm.fruit.$invalid && !testForm.fruit.$pristine}">
      <test ng-model="fruit" field="testForm.fruit"></test>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

but the only way I can get notified of the validation change is with the watch on the field, not on the coordinate.  What needs to be done to so that I don't have to pass in the field to watch validity?

Attached is a plunker illustrating the issue

http://plnkr.co/edit/cIiv2PNc6te42lMshxJE?p=preview

Comment: Im not entirely getting under what condition the form should or should not be valid.

Comment: I tried to keep this simple, so right now the only thing that determines validity is the field that is marked as required is filled out.  In my actual app, it needs to be of a particular format, but again just trying to keep it simple.  The real key is being able to detect that the validity of the input element has changed regardless of the conditions of validity.  Does that make sense?